# Java layout problem

Tags: java, swing

I've got 3 classes in my program.

```
public class Field extends JLabel{

    private int x, y;

    public Field(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        setOpaque(true);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));
        if((x + y) % 2 == 0)
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        else
            setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }


public class Board extends JPanel{

    public Field[][] fields = new Field[8][8];

    public Board(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550,550));
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        fillBoard();
    }

    private void fillBoard(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j){
                fields[i][j] = new Field(i, j);
                add(fields[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

public class GUI extends JFrame{

    public Board board;

    private GUI(){
        board = new Board();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(board);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new GUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Whenever I run the program, [this](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/8900/przechwytywanieqz.jpg) appears instead of a yellow-green board. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you expect it to look like?

Comment: When I run your code, I get a green/yellow checkerboard with a slight red border on the right side and on the bottom.

Comment: Presumably just a typo in the question but the class `Field` doesn't get closed

Comment: Note that you should generally call `pack()` before `setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted code does not compile. Re-factoring into nested classes made it work <strike>correctly</strike> as shown, so I'm guessing you have a project level problem.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private Board board;

    private GUI() {
        board = new Board();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(board);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI();
            }
        });
    }

    class Board extends JPanel {

        public Field[][] fields = new Field[8][8];

        public Board() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 550));
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            fillBoard();
        }

        private void fillBoard() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
                    fields[i][j] = new Field(i, j);
                    add(fields[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Field extends JLabel {

        private int x, y;

        public Field(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            setOpaque(true);
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 75));
            if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
                setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, this is really just a picture of @Hovercraft Full Of Eels' insightful comment.

Comment: best for 2D Graphics around +1

Answer (score -1):

You should set layout manager and add component to the contentPane on JFrame, inside GUI you should call:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
getContentPane().add(board);
```

Your code compiles if both Board and Field are refactored to inner classes, but the result looks like this
[image: Result]

To make the interface look without the red line comment  `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550,550));` on your Board constructor so it become:

```
public Board(){
        int rows = 8,cols = 8;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550,550));
    setBackground(Color.RED);
    fillBoard();
}
```

[image: The result after removing setPreferredSize()]

Comment: Calling those methods directly on the `JFrame` (as the OP is doing) just delegates to the content pane, this should make no difference.

Comment: He didn't mention what version of jdk he was working with so my answer is not really wrong per se

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're absolutely right.  It looks like this behaviour was added (or at least documented) starting in Java 5.  But I would hope the OP isn't using a dreadfully out of date version of Java.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this didn't solve my problem. I am using the newest Java version - jre6